# Should a six wire stepper motor not have two coils that are separate from each other?

Tags: stepper-motor

My understanding is that a six wire stepper motor contains two coils. Both of these coils are separate from each other, meaning that the impedance between any two wires, one from each coil will be infinite.

When I took impedance measurements on a stepper motor that I salvaged -- I got the following readings, all in Ohms.

[image]

Would any help at understanding what I'm looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like the commons are tied together and it looks (from the numbers) like you have a particularly crummy meter that probably reads almost 2 ohms with the leads shorted.

That would explain the numbers if you subtract ~2 ohms from each measurement and the stepper is a conventional 6-wire unipolar stepper with 10\$\Omega\$ coils. As below [from here](https://learn.adafruit.com/all-about-stepper-motors/types-of-steppers), but with two wires connected to the common.

[image]

Tying the commons together is not a problem since they're normally connected together anyway. A possibility would be that they are tied together because there is an internal thermal cutout in series.